# Is this even possible?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, markov-process, conditional-independence

How is this possible:

If $P (Z|Y, X) = P(Z|Y)$ AND $P(X|Y,Z)= P(X|Y)$

How can these two be equal:    $$P (Z|Y,X) = P(X|Y,Z)$$

[image]

Comment: I've edited your question, but your wording is vague. Can you please clarify what you mean? Do you ask if it's always the case that $P(Z|Y,X)=P(X|Y,Z)$ given the conditions in the beginning, which are actually equivalent.

Comment: I have been given these two as Markov's property and the second one as reverse Markov. I have to show these equivalents but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: So, just to reiterate, you're asking if $P(Z|Y,X)=P(X|Y,Z)$ is always correct or not given the information in your first `If .. and ..` statement?

Comment: Yes sorry, if ...and are just words nothing related.

Comment: I have edited the question giving more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement $\mathbb P (Z|Y, X) = \mathbb P(Z|Y)$ means that $Z$ and $X$ are conditionally independent given $Y$ (a), which directly means $\mathbb P(X|Y,Z)=\mathbb P(X|Y)$ (which is (b)). So, the given statements are equivalent. But, the final statement $\mathbb P(Z|Y,X)=\mathbb P(X|Y,Z)$ is not always correct.

You can see both using Bayes Rule, e,g. for (a)
$$\mathbb P(X,Z|Y)=\mathbb P(Z|X,Y)\mathbb P(X|Y)=\mathbb P(Z|Y)\mathbb P(X|Y)$$